# do while: Go back -1 day until condition is true

Tags: php, do-while

How can I setup a `do while` condition that goes back -1 day until my array has 10 elements?

Here is my test code:

```
$date = '2016-01-24';

$array = [];

$i = 0;

do {

    $days_back = '-' . $i++ . ' day';

    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $date->modify($days_back);
    $date = $date->format('Y-m-d');

    echo '<br /> $date: ' . $date . ' // $days_back: ' . $days_back . ' // $i: ' . $i . '<br />';

    array_push(
        $array,
        array($date),
        array($days_back)
    );

} while (count($array) < 10);
```

Here is my output:

```
$date: 2016-01-24 // $days_back: -0 day // $i: 1
$date: 2016-01-23 // $days_back: -1 day // $i: 2
$date: 2016-01-21 // $days_back: -2 day // $i: 3
$date: 2016-01-18 // $days_back: -3 day // $i: 4
$date: 2016-01-14 // $days_back: -4 day // $i: 5
```

But output of `$date` is incorrect here. It jumps too high between runs, but it should be linear: 24, 23, 22, 21 etc.

Comment: You either need to modify the original date with -$i days, or modify the current date with only -1 day. Seems straightforward.

Comment: @rjdown: Yes, you're correct. -1 day on the date is all I needed.

Comment: Think about what you're doing...you're setting the `$date` variable to the new date for each iteration. Therefore when you subtract 3 days, you're subtracting that from `2016-01-21` and NOT your original date of `2016-01-24` which is why the next date is the 18th.

Comment: @Lee just to make what Andy has said simplier. Change `$date = '2016-01-24';` into `$startDate= '2016-01-24';` then change `$date = new DateTime($date);` into `$date = new DateTime($startDate);`

Answer (score 0):

Just need to rename $date variable at two places. Here is the code

```
$currentDate = '2016-01-24';
$array = [];
$i = 0;
do {
    $days_back = '-' . $i++ . ' day';
    $date = new DateTime($currentDate);
    $date->modify($days_back);
    $date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    echo '<br /> $date: ' . $date . ' // $days_back: ' . $days_back . ' // $i: ' . $i . '<br />';
    array_push(
        $array,
        array($date),
        array($days_back)
    );
} while (count($array) < 10);
```